# change key val in django to list

Tags: python, django

how to change this format to simple list

```
 [{'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 100}, {'qte': 350}, {'qte': 11}]
```

it's result of  this requête

```
inst = Produit.objects.values('qte')
print inst
```

i need to be like this  format

```
[100,100,100,100,100,100.....]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead of `values` with `flat=True` parameter.

```
inst = Produit.objects.values_list('qte', flat=True)
```